# python3 --version shows "NameError: name 'python3' is not defined"

Tags: python, command

When we type

```
python3 --version (or --V)
```

it is supposed to show us the version of the python right?

However, when I do this I get the following error:

> NameError: name 'python3' is not defined

This is also the case when I tried to install the pip by using

```
>>> python3 get-pip.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python3 get-pip.py
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`python3` is *not Python syntax*, it is the *Python binary itself*, the thing you run to get to the interactive interpreter.

You are confusing the *command line* with the Python prompt. Open a console (Windows) or terminal (Linux, Mac), the same place you'd use `dir` or `ls` to explore your filesystem from the command line.

If you are typing at a `>>>` or `In [number]:` prompt you are in the wrong place, that's the Python interpreter itself and it only takes Python syntax. If you started the Python prompt from a command line, *exit* at this point and go back to the command line. If you started the interpreter from IDLE or in an IDE, then you need to open a terminal or console as a separate program.

Other programs that people often confuse for Python syntax; each of these is actually a program to run in your command prompt:

- `python`, `python2.7`, `python3.5`, etc.
- `pip` or `pip3`
- `virtualenv`
- `ipython`
- `easy_install`
- `django-admin`
- `conda`
- `flask`
- `scrapy`
- `setup.py` -- this is a script you need to run with `python setup.py [...]`.
- Any of the above together with `sudo`.

with many more variations possible depending on what tools and libraries you have installed and what you are trying to do.

If given arguments, you'll get a `SyntaxError` exception instead, but the underlying cause is the same:

```
>>> pip install foobar
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install foobar
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using windows you can try in a Python prompt:

```
>>>>import pip
>>>>pip.main(['install', 'foobar'])
```

Comment: Yes, many command-line tools are built with Python itself and their code can usually be imported to achieve the same thing. But the syntax differs from project to project, and for the level of experience that leads to making this mistake, figuring out the exact Python API for the tool is usually well beyond reach.

Comment: And this is not limited to Windows, `import pip` and `pip.main()` would work on any OS.