# import module form the neighbors but report syntax error

Tags: python

I am following an instruction to learn data structure but encounter such an error:

the file system

```
├── 7.linkedList
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── circular_queue.py
│   ├── doubly_linked_base.py
│   ├── favorites_list.py
│   ├── favorites_list_mtf.py
│   ├── insertion_sort_positional.py
│   ├── linkedList.c
│   ├── linked_deque.py
│   ├── linked_queue.py
│   ├── linked_stack.py
│   ├── positional_list.py
│   └── singlyllist.py
├── 8.Tree
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── binary_tree.py
│   ├── depth.py
│   ├── euler_tour.py
│   ├── expression_tree.py
│   ├── linked_binary_tree.py
│   ├── traversal_examples.py
│   └── tree.py
```

in the 8.Tree.tree.py, there is codes

```
from ..7.LinkedList.linked_queue import LinkedQueue
import collections

class Tree:
  """Abstract base class representing a tree structure."""
```

which import function from 7.LinkedList.linked_queue

```
In [14]: python /me/Desktop/PubRepo/Algorithms/Algorithms_Wiley/8.Tree/tree.py
  File "<ipython-input-14-89fcb9d20232>", line 1
    python /me/Desktop/PubRepo/Algorithms/Algorithms_Wiley/8.Tree/tree.py
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

it report invalid syntax

I tried `../7.LinkedList.linked_queue`, it also not work.

How could I solve the problem?

Comment: Don't use special characters in file names and directory names. Only use characters that are valid in a Python identifier (letters, digits and the underscore).

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845768/python3-version-shows-nameerror-name-python3-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the names pattern, you should make your repository as a lib in advance with `__init__`